# Continuity of f with supremum metric - Lipschitz condition

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, lipschitz-functions

Let $$ X=C([0,1]) $$ $$ f: [0,1] \rightarrow {R}  $$ with supremum metric:

$$  d(f,g)=\sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)| $$
where $$ f,g \in X
$$
 Check if  $$F: X \rightarrow X $$  $$ F(f)=\arctan{(f(x))} $$ is continous

**My attempt:**
I want to say that this function fulfils Lipschitz contidion. 
I have:
$$ d(F(f), G(g))= \sup_{x \in [0,1]}|\arctan{f(x)}-\arctan{g(x)}|$$
This is the point where I am stuck. I wanted to say that 
$$ \sup_{x \in [0,1]}|\arctan{f(x)}-\arctan{g(x)}|\leqslant \sup_{x \in [0,1]}|f(x)-g(x)|$$
Then it would be everything, but I'm not sure that this is true. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Apply the mean value theorem and the fact that $\frac{d}{dx} \arctan x = \frac{1}{1+x^2}$.

Comment: Have look: https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Arctangents

Answer (score 1):

Actually,

Use Lagrange inequality giving :

$$ \exists c\in]0,\frac{\pi}{2}[, \forall(p,q)\in]0,\frac{\pi}{2}[ , (\arctan(p) -\arctan(q)) \leq |p-q|*\arctan'(c) $$

Comment: Have look at this.